# Unity don't load images inside the engine

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmpLM.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73NYN.png)

not even an image inside the engine loads, does anyone know what it could be?

Comment: My first guess is your machine is under spec so you are out of resources

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, your Unity Editor source template is corrupted. If the problem is not resolved after restart unity and other projects are the same, it is better to reinstall unity. Otherwise the best option is to move the Assets to a new project.

Comment: this error remains in all projects, I already tried to reinstall, and I tried with other versions of unity, but the error persists

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to catch what causes an error with this post, but you can try the image file to Sprite.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).